# React Native Functional Component react-native-select2 onSelected Value not update

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

React Native Functional Component  react-native-select2 onSelected Value not updateing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@schmelman/rns2

https://snack.expo.dev/@prem18mca/select2-functional

https://snack.expo.dev/@prem18mca/select2

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Select2 from "react-native-select-two"
// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(mockData);
  const mockData = [
  { id: 1, name: "React Native Developer", checked: true}, // set default checked for render option item
  { id: 2, name: "Android Developer", color: '#f00' },
  { id: 3, name: "iOS Developer", color: '#f00' }
]
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.
      </Text>
      <Select2
          style={{ borderRadius: 5 }}
          colorTheme="blue"
          popupTitle="Select item"
          title="Select item"
          data={mockData}
          onSelect={data => {
           setData({ data })
          }}
          cancelButtonText = "Cancel"
          selectButtonText = "Select"
          onRemoveItem={data => {
           setData({ data })
          }}
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update with npm i @marcelodiegues/react-native-select2. If it doesn't work, show your error message

Comment: I have Updated i have attached the expo there